# Azure Communication Service Queue

Tags: python, azure, azure-communication-services

Does anyone know how can i queue azure emails and send them in a queue?

Like for example I wanna to  create a job to send emails at 10:00 at noon, so it should send that time, not instantly like Azure provides in their documentation. in python.

```
def _send(self, data: Dict[str, Any], recipients: List[CustomUser]) -> None:
    self._email_template.validate_data(data)
    self._initialize_message()
    relative_link = self._email_template.get_relative_link(data)
    context = self._email_template.get_template_context(data)
    context.update({"relative_link": relative_link})
    self._message.update({"recipients": {"to": self._get_recipients(recipients)}})
    self._message["content"].update({"html": self._render_template(context)})
    try:
        client = self._initialize_connection()
        response = client.begin_send(self._message)

    except Exception as ex:
        logger.error(f"Error occurred during email sending: {ex}")
        raise ex
```

i just use being_send, there is also async being_send, but its not solving my problem. Should i use kafka and rabbirmq for triggering messages from my app? I would prefer use something which offers Azure tbh. Sorry, i mean its my 1st time on stackoverflow, so I'm kinda shy lol

Comment: please share the code you tried

Comment: Other method is create an Azure function of Python with a timer trigger and Set a timer trigger for the function to run at the desired time to send emails.

Comment: i mean that's kinda helpful. Uploaded my code

Answer (score 0):

The sample below is an Azure Functions Python script that uses the Azure Communication Services Email SDK to send an email using a timer trigger.

The function sets a timer trigger to run at the desired time for sending emails, and the timer interval is appropriately set for your use case.

```py
import datetime
import logging
from azure.communication.email import EmailClient
import azure.functions as func

# Replace the following with your actual connection string
connection_string = "endpoint=https://<resource-name>.communication.azure.com/;accessKey=<Base64-Encoded-Key>"

# Initialize the EmailClient using the connection string
email_client = EmailClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)

    # Define the email message
    message = {
        "content": {
            "subject": "This is the subject",
            "plainText": "This is the body",
            "html": "<html><h1>This is the body</h1></html>"
        },
        "recipients": {
            "to": [
                {
                    "address": "Receiver@domain.com",
                    "displayName": "Customer Name"
                }
            ]
        },
        "senderAddress": "sender@contoso.com"
    }

    # Send the email message and retrieve the result
    poller = email_client.begin_send(message)
    result = poller.result()

    # Print the result (status and details)
    logging.info("Email sent successfully!")
    logging.info(result)
```

**Output:**
[image]

[image]

```py
import datetime
import logging
from typing import Dict, Any, List
from azure.communication.email import EmailClient
import azure.functions as func

# Replace the following with your actual connection string
connection_string = "endpoint=https://<resource-name>.communication.azure.com/;accessKey=<Base64-Encoded-Key>"

# Initialize the EmailClient using the connection string
email_client = EmailClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

# CustomUser class definition (replace with your actual implementation)
class CustomUser:
    def __init__(self, email: str, name: str):
        self.email = email
        self.name = name

class EmailSender:
    def __init__(self):
        # Add your email template initialization logic here
        pass

    def _initialize_connection(self):
        # Replace this with your actual logic to initialize the connection
        return EmailClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

    def _send(self, data: Dict[str, Any], recipients: List[CustomUser]) -> None:
        # Your existing _send method implementation
        client = self._initialize_connection()
        context = {"key": "value"}  # Replace with your actual data
        message = {
            "content": {
                "subject": "This is the subject",
                "plainText": "This is the body",
                "html": "<html><h1>This is the body</h1></html>",  # Replace with your HTML template
            },
            "recipients": {"to": self._get_recipients(recipients)},
            "senderAddress": "sender@contoso.com",
        }
        client.begin_send(message).result()

    def _get_recipients(self, recipients: List[CustomUser]) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
        # Replace this with your logic to convert CustomUser instances to recipients dictionary
        return [{"address": user.email, "displayName": user.name} for user in recipients]

# Azure Function
def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc
    ).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)

    # Your email data and recipients
    email_data = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}  # Replace with your actual data
    recipients_list = [CustomUser(email="Receiver@domain.com", name="Recipient Name")]

    # Create an instance of EmailSender
    email_sender = EmailSender()

    try:
        # Call the _send method to send the email
        email_sender._send(email_data, recipients_list)

        logging.info("Email sent successfully!")
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.error(f"Error occurred during email sending: {ex}")
        # Handle the exception as needed
        raise ex
```